# MS Access Error 3274 & 2083

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, export-to-excel

So I have this code for exporting my queries. Most the time the query will work, but random times it will give me error 2083 and once in a while error 3274. What could be causing these errors? I have ran this function with the same query results, sometimes it will work, sometimes not.

3274: External table is not in the expected format.

2083: The database is read-only. You can't save changes made to data or object definitions in this database.

```
Public Function TreatyCodingExport()    
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "QUERY1", path, True, "worksheet1"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "QUERY2", path, True, "worksheet2"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "QUERY3", path, True, "worksheet3"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "QUERY4", path, True, "worksheet4"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "QUERY5", path, True, "worksheet5"
    End Function
```